# Best approach of doing full outer join on parse.com with Xamarin.Android (c#)

Tags: c#, database, parse-platform, xamarin, outer-join

I have this common scenario of displaying comments with user details and I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this on Parse.
*(Let's say we have a class comment: id, post, user and a class user: id, photo, name).*

I was trying to do something like this that it isn't possible on Parse:

```
var userDetails = ParseObject.GetQuery("User");

var query = ParseObject.GetQuery ("Review")
    .WhereEqualTo ("business", application.currentBusiness)
    .WhereMatchesQuery ("user", userDetails);
```

It is not working because users is a Relation, let me explain more:

From what I have read on [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/dotnet/guide) there are 2 ways to have relations in parse. one with arrays and one with pointers.

Arrays are good when you want to **include** the whole object (in my case the user) but not for more than 100 results.

Pointers are better for a big database but in order to get for every comment the user details I will have to do one extra query.. that's a lot of queries...

So my options are those I think:

**1)** Retrieve the whole query with a full outer join with arrays
The problem with this is the speed if my app is getting bigger and bigger

**2)**  Retrieve the whole query with a full outer join with relations
Many many queries. I will reach the parse.com limit of request/sec very fast.

**3)** Store the details I want in the comments class along the User_ID
This might be a good idea but I'm using **Login with Facebook** and after the login, the user photos will be updated if it has change since the last time, so if I want to use this idea I have to somehow disable the update of the photo.

**4)** Use arrays and retrieve only a certain number of comments each time.
This sounds like the best approach, I will get every time around 50 seconds and I can implement a ListView that will load more comments when we are reaching the end of the List.

What do you think guys? What do I have to do? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution after all was to use **Pointer** for the User.
With the pointer and the **.Include** you can get the whole user object without doing many queries and without destroying the connection of the User class with the comments class by storing the whole User object on the Comment class, nice.

Also if someone want to know how to make a join with pointers and how to retrieve the object then here is q query to retrieve comment and photo:

```
var query = ParseObject.GetQuery ("Comments")
            .WhereEqualTo ("Article", _article)
            .Include ("user");
```

And here is how to access the photo

```
_user.photo = queryResult.Get<ParseObject>("user").Get<ParseFile>("profile_pic").Url;
```